# Handling Apollo Client Errors from Provider

Tags: javascript, reactjs, graphql, apollo, apollo-client

I have a small situation on Apollo Client and handling error in use Mutation.

here is my calling mutation:

```
const [createUser, { data, loading, error }] = useMutation(CREATE_USER)
```

When I console the error i have this response:
[image]

It doesn't look good for me, i only want the message error.

So i started to search for some apollo client error handling:

```
const errorLink = onError(({ graphQLErrors }) => {
  if (graphQLErrors) {
    console.log(graphQLErrors)
  }
})
const httpLink = new HttpLink({ uri: 'http://localhost:8000/graphql' })
const appLink = from([errorLink, httpLink])

export const ApolloClientProvider = new ApolloClient({
  link: appLink,
  cache: new InMemoryCache(),
})
```

When the request is done, i got the error from errorLink, graphQLErrors console log and looks fine:
[image]

It is possible to send or set the error to be only the `message` in useMutation?

Answer (score 0):

You can't change the way that errors are returned unless you replace the error handler on the server side. Since there can be more than one error, errors are returned as an array.

Here's a client-side function that can help you manipulate Apollo errors. It returns an array of strings (one for each error) as well as a couple booleans indicating whether you got an authentication or networking error.

```
// utility to process Apollo GraphQL errors
import { ApolloError } from '@apollo/client/errors';

export const apolloErrorToStrings = (apolloError: ApolloError) => {
  const errorArray: Array<string> = [];
  let isNetworkError = false,
    isAuthenticationError = false;

  if (apolloError.graphQLErrors) {
    apolloError.graphQLErrors.forEach((error) => {
      errorArray.push(
        `${error.extensions?.code || 'unknown'}: ${error.message}`
      );
      if (error.extensions?.code === 'UNAUTHENTICATED')
        isAuthenticationError = true;
    });
  }
  if (apolloError.networkError) {
    errorArray.push('CONNECTION FAILED: Are you connected to the internet?');
    isNetworkError = true;
  }
  return { errorArray, isNetworkError, isAuthenticationError };
};
```

Comment: thank you Michel, i understand, but where i should use apolloErrorToStrings?

Comment: Wherever you need to process these errors! For example after a query or mutation.